# Data plotting SQL database link set up in QGIS

Tags: qgis, sql-server

We have a SQL database link set up in QGIS which is working well. However, the points plotted in different locations than when the points are downloaded and plotted from a non-database file.

The same CRS files are used in both cases and is the same as the project.

In addition, the miss plotting by the SQL database  points is not constant and some even plot on top of each other when the co-ordinates are separated.

Is it a QGIS bug or operator error on our part?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. We are a *problem-solving* site, not a bug-reporting one. Fortunately, this seem more likely to be operator error. Unfortunately, you'd need to provide details on how exactly you loaded the data into the database, and how you plotted the non-database file before we could suggest which procedure was suspect. Of particular concern is the vertex order (which is usually X,Y -- lat,lon is Y,X).

Comment: I'd say different versions of the libraries of the projections, PROJ/EPSG. Can you show both librarys in QGIS and the SQL system? In QGIS it is in the HELP|ABOUT menu item - for 3.36 I'm seeing;
PROJ version
9.3.1
EPSG Registry database version
v10.098 (2023-11-24)

Comment: Out of interest, how is your database enabled to have spatial capability?

Comment: Data in the SQL database is surveyed using a RTK GPS and is surveyed in the CRS grid in question.  This CRS grid is assigned to the database co-ordinates when the database connection is made.   XYZ co-ordinates are assigned .

Comment: Data in the SQL database is surveyed using a RTK GPS and is surveyed in the CRS grid in question.  This CRS grid is assigned to the database co-ordinates when the database connection is made.   XYZ co-ordinates are assigned .  This link plots in the wrong place(verified by orthor referenced images plus other survey) with the error being randomly orienteted around the actual point. When the same data is exported from the SQL database and loaded from a CSV (with the same assigned CRS grid as the SQL link and as surveyed) the data plots in the correct position